# Making the Smart Map field translatable

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I have a multi-language site. So I need to show slightly different address data, depending on the current locale. Especially regarding the city and country field.

Example:

**DE**

```
Venloer Str. 200
Köln
Deutschland
```

**EN**

```
Venloer Str. 200
Cologne
Germany
```

I tried marking the field as translatable, but it hasn’t worked out of the box and I couldn’t find any documentation on this.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Smart Map doesn't currently support the ability to make an Address translatable.** It's on the feature request list, and will be implemented at some point in the future.

In the meantime, you can use [static translations](https://craftcms.com/support/static-translations) to handle names of common cities & countries:

```
City: {{ entry.location.city | t }}
Country: {{ entry.location.country | t }}
```

** The `t` filter is an alias for [`translate`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#translate-or-t).*